# how to bind webservice result to listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I want to display list of medicines coming from remote database using webservice
the output as given below

```
md1
md2
md2...etc
```

for this i wrote the following client but its not working ,error came.
please help me for developing windows phone app

```
public partial class Antocids : PhoneApplicationPage
{
  ObservableCollection<Class1> p = new ObservableCollection<Class1>();

  public Antocids()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    listBox1.DataContext = p; 
     ServiceReference3.ProductsClient client = new ServiceReference3.ProductsClient();
    client.getProdDetailsCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference3.getProdDetailsCompletedEventArgs>(client_getProdDetailsCompleted);
    client.getProdDetailsAsync();
  }
  private void client_getProdDetailsCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference3.getProdDetailsCompletedEventArgs e)
  {

    p.Clear(); // assuming you want to clear the data each time you get a new result 
    foreach (var result in e.Result)
        p.Add(result); // here i got the error the error is invalid arguments are passed to overloaded method add() 

  }
}
```

Comment: when you debug... does e.Result give you the right values?

Comment: What is the type of that `e.Result` enumerable? Should be `Class1` to be accepted by the `p.Add()` method...

Answer (score 0):

try this  `p.Add((Class1)result);`

Comment: yes but in this case  am getting error at the following code p.Add(result);